# Simple chess bot

Tags: code-golf, chess

*Inspired by [this](https://github.com/bolknote/SedChess)*

Implement simple chess bot (with console or GUI) that has following features:

1. [Pseudo-]graphically showing the board;
2. Accepting user moves and making their own moves;
3. Playing by basic chess rules (not doing illegal moves);
4. Making at least minimally reasonable moves (no random moves, a player making random valid moves against the bot should lose most times).

In general, implement something like "SedChess" (linked above) in minimum number of bytes.

Optional:

1. Advances rules like castling, stalemate detection, en passant, etc;
2. Checking validity of user inputs;
3. Analysing more than 1 move in depth;

Limitations:

1. No networking;
2. No dependance on chess-specific libraries (unless they are included in the language and language's standard library) or programs;
3. No lame tricks like showing two boards and requesting user play two games (with himself).

Comment: Do you think anyone can compete with [this](http://js1k.com/2010-first/demo/435)?

Comment: Nice. Maybe somebody want to try more languages for this problem.

Comment: You describe a major undertaking, not a puzzle.

Comment: There are other major undertakings like golfing an x86 emulator here.

Comment: This looks rather like an extension of [Calculate all legal moves](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10843), which so far has no submissions. If you want anyone to attempt an answer, you might be better off restricting the question to the half which that one doesn't cover - i.e. estimating a board's value.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Which btw was solved already [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3237/1490) ;-) Unfortunately no one tried another solution in either question.

Comment: @ugoren Yes I do believe so. I beat that chess bot in a match of chess.

Comment: See also: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37251/chess-tournament

Comment: [This one posted by ugoren][1] doesn't recognize checkmate or castling or en passant.


  [1]: http://js1k.com/2010-first/demo/435

Comment: @ugoren You can't castling :/ But else, nice bot for a 1k bytes!